# Change font-size in an Ionic input text-area

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I can't seem to change the font-size for the Ionic input. I've tried

```
input {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

but that doesn't work. However,

```
input {
    font-family: Times;
}
```

works, so I don't know what exactly is the problem. I can't even change the height of the input as

```
input {
    height:100px;
}
```

does not work.

However, when I take out the line in my HTML referencing the Ionic CSS, (lib\ionic\css\ionic.css), my CSS works. I think my CSS should be overriding the Ionic CSS as my CSS comes after it, so what's happening, and how do I fix it?

EDIT:

Even if I put !important, it doesn't work. Interestingly enough,

```
input {
     height:100px; !important
     font-family: Times;
}
```

makes it so that the font doesn't change, while

input {
         font-family: Times;
         height:100px; !important
    }

does change the font.

EDIT2: The problem was with selector specificity:

```
 textarea, input[type="text"]... {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 34px;
  color: #111;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

was overriding it, so I just changed my CSS to

```
input[type="text"] {
font-size:30px;
}
```

and it worked!

Comment: Never ever use !important !! It sounds like there is a problem with selector specificity. What does dev tools say when you inspect the element?

Comment: You're right!  
`textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], ... {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 34px;
  color: #111;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
}`
is showing through. Thank you so much!

Comment: Then just overwrite the required selector that you need. You can also add more specificity to it like class of parent element. That way the loading order won't matter really.

Comment: Yes! (For letter requirement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that the specificity stated in the framework is greater than what you are providing in your CSS.

Using dev tools to track down the specific style by inspecting the element should show you how the framework defined its selector.

As some have mentioned, using `!important`could solve this, but it is not a recommended solution as it cheat its way to the max specificity and can't be overwritten later on, except by being more specific with a selector and including the important statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `!important` before semicolon.

Comment: You should never use !important to overwrite styles if possible. CSS has clear specificity and it's not hard to track it down.

Comment: But when you are using ionic and you are not aware of each of the styles that it gives, then you may need to use !important.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here https://ionicframework.com/docs/v6/api/textarea#theming in the docs you should not try to change general styles of "input" or "textarea". Instead simply use a custom class:

```
<ion-input class="myinputstyles" ....
<ion-textarea class="myinputstyles" ....
```

You can change all the needed styles in your component-css:

```
.myinputstyles {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```